# Закрытие модального окна при ошибке

Tags: javascript, html, input, modal, submit

Помогите пожалуйста с проблемой, при нажатии на кнопку "Отправить" закрывается модальное окно, даже если поля пустые, то есть он выдаёт ошибку и обводит пустые поля - всё как надо, но скрывает модальное окно из-за чего надо пользователю его вновь вызывать самому - т.е. форму. Как исправить это?
Код формы такой:

```
<form class="form js-form" method="POST" action="./php/telegrambot.php">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <h1 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Заявка</h1>
            <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
    </div>

    <div class="modal-body bg-light">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-6">
                <label class="form-label"><b>Имя:</b></label>
                <input class="form-control input js-input">
            </div>
            <div class="col-6">
                <label class="form-label"><b>Контактный номер:</b></label>
                <input class="form-control input js-input">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
                    
    <div class="modal-footer bg-danger border-top">
        <div class="content-center">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-primary border-2" data-bs-toggle="modal">Отправить</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Код на проверку js написал вот такой:

```
let form = document.querySelector('.js-form'),
    formInputs = document.querySelectorAll('.js-input');

form.onsubmit = function () {
    let emptyInputs = Array.from(formInputs).filter(input => input.value === '');

    formInputs.forEach(function (input) {
        if (input.value === '') {
            input.classList.add('error');

        } else {
            input.classList.remove('error');
        }
    });

    if (emptyInputs.length !== 0) {
        console.log('inputs not filled');
        return false;
    }
}
```

Где добавить изменения?

Answer (score 0):

```
form.onsubmit = function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    ...
    ...
    далее по тексту
```

---

либо в самом конце `form.onsubmit` дописать `return false`. Думаю тоже должно помочь

Comment: Дописал внизу: if (emptyInputs.length !== 0) {
        console.log('inputs not filled');
        return false;
    }
   return false;
}
Но не помогло, окошко всё равно закрывает при нажатии на кнопку...